# NLP Text classification Based on User comments

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I am new to the machine learning and wanted to work on this problem statement.
I have got some of the user comments about products and based on those comments, my model should summarize and give me the output for that text sentence.

Example :-

1. User commented "Device Battery is heating up", based on this comment my model should summarize this to "Battery issue".
2. User commented "Cracked Screen", based on this comment my model should summarize this to "Display issue".

Can anyone suggest me which model should be the best fit for my problem statement or any model code samples would be really helpful.

I have tried with TF-IDF, and MB Naive bayes classifier but those are not helpful. I think topic modelling can help me here.

Comment: I think you'd need to figure out your labels for the model.

Do you have a set of labels, i.e., categories for summaries? If you can figure that, it can be a classification problems.

Comment: I don't have set of labels because the dataset is huge and i can't figure it out manually. Is there any way that machine can do this on its own and learn on it's own. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a problem for an encoder-decoder DNN. You can translate the words e.g. with word2vec to vectors and feed the sentences into an encoder-model. This will give you another vector for a second model (decoder) which gives you the final classification. 
For reference take a look at the deep learning course by Andrew Ng on Coursera (Sequence models).